# Pass values between components in Angular 7

Tags: angular7

I have a main form that collects some user attributes, then calls service from the typecript. Once the values are returned from Service's http call, I want to bring up another html to display the received results(this is present in another component in my design). I want to store the received results in a model and then display the second page by extracting model properties, but I cant seem to get it to work.

form.component.ts

```
@Output() weatherCardEventEmitter = new EventEmitter<weatherCardModal>();
getWeatherCardDetails(): void {
    this.cardService.getWeatherCardDetails(this.lat, this.lon)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.weatherCardEventEmitter.emit(data);//trying to emit it to card component
      });
```

card.component.ts where I am trying to get the values from above component.

```
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
              @Input() weatherCard: weatherCardModal;
              constructor() { }
              ngOnInit() {}
            }
              }
```

My app.module.ts

```
export class AppModule {
  public data: weatherCardModal;

  handleResults(searchObj){
    this.data = searchObj;
  }
 }
```

My app.module.html

```
<app-form (weatherCardEventEmitter)="handleResults($event)"> </app-form>
<app-card [weatherCard]= "data"></app-card>
<app-daily-details-card></app-daily-details-card>>
```

Please let me know 1>how to store the value received from service call in modal in form.component.ts.  2.and what am I doing wrong in sending the values from form component to card component. I tried binding in app.module as well but nothing works. I searched and found a code that required the handleResults() in app component, but is it really need. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb) link to the best solution for you. Hope this helps!